# How to split datestamp in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a datestamp in this format on A2:

```
18.11.2015 15:37:13
```

How can I split this into date and time so that I have date in A3 and time in A4?

I want to do this because datestamp does not sort properly as a number.

I found several answers to this question with various answers but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't a simple split() be enough ? In B2:

```
=split(A2, " ")
```

Alternatively, in B2:

```
={INT(A2), timevalue(A2)}
```

Make sure to format col B as DATE and col C as TIME and see if that works?

Comment: @pnuts: I don't think that is correct. Enter =now() in a cell and try the split method as used above?

Comment: Tested on a timestamp (from form submission) and I don't see any difference in functionality.

Comment: Oh, you mean that the value in A2 is probably text? I'd agree with that. But in that case, both formulas should work. Or were you not commenting on the proposed formulas?

Comment: What if we enter =="01.06.2018 21:39:18" in a cell ? Using split I get the date and the time and both seem to sort properly as number. Checking with isnumber() both return 'true'.  Same goes for the second formula (but output needs to formatted as 'date' and 'time'. ?

Comment: Weird. Most likely it will have something to do with locale settings?

Comment: No problem, pnuts. I'm glad we were able to sort this out ;-).

Answer (score 2):

To get the date and time in those cells you can do the following:
`A3`: `=DATE(MID(A2,7,4),MID(A2,4,2),LEFT(A2,2))`
`A4`: `=TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A2,8))`

It's essentially extracting the essential parts for year/month/day from the string in A2 to get the needed order for date. The time is already properly formatted and can be used with Timevalue, we just need to extract the substring.

The date and time values can then be formatted in any way you want them.